# Tengo un error al compilar un proyecto en ionic1

Tags: ionic

Mi problema es que al compilar la aplicacion no me genera la apk,pero tampoco me genera algun error quien me pueda ayudar

Comment: A esta pregunta le falta información clave: ¿cómo estás intentando compilar? ¿Usas algún IDE? ¿Cuál es tu código? Necesitamos más detalles.

Answer (score 1):

Por pasos:

- Abre un terminal (windows o linux)
- Posicionate a en la carpeta donde reside tu proyecto
- Ejecuta `ionic build android` o `ionic cordova build android` (si tienes actualizado el cli )
- Copianos la respuesta que aparece.

> Intenta la próxima vez aportar más información que lo que has dicho y nada, es lo mismo.